# TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. from idb after upgrade to typescript 4.4

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, indexeddb, typescript-generics

I used use `idb` to build up my indexDB on client side. In typescript, 3.8, it is fine without problem. however, I get the error
`'TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` after upgrade to typescript, 4.4. How can I resolve it?

```
import * as idb from 'idb';
const buildDb = async ({db}) => {
  const oldDB = await idb.openDB('user', 1);
  db.createObjectStore('dbKey'); //TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
};
```

Comment: The idb library is not an es6 module last i checked. It does not export anything. To import it you want to use its global declaration as a side effect of the module load. Change your import to `import 'idb';`. The module will get loaded, the variable `idb` will be declared in global scope as a side effect, and then your code will use the global. The `import * as idb` is declaring a variable that is void (never), and overwriting the implicit global, so you need to stop doing that.

Comment: @Josh i change to import idb from 'idb'. I still have the same error.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to specify the type of the `db` parameter to the `buildDb` function?

Comment: You cannot use `import idb from 'idb';`. You need to literally write `import 'idb';`. Literally. Do not add "idb from" there.

Comment: thank you. after some search, I found one PR from idb. https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb/issues/222. i resolve the issue by upgrade idb version from 6.0.x to 6.1